# Is there a default C++ comparator for user defined structure?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
int main() {
    map<TreeNode*,int> mp;
    TreeNode* x=new TreeNode(4);
    TreeNode* y=new TreeNode(5);
    TreeNode* z=new TreeNode(6);
    mp[x]=1;
    mp[y]=2;
    mp[z]=3;

    cout<<mp[x]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles and gives the desired outut but why don't we need to define a custom comparator to create the map mp; Does C++ does it itself? Same with unordered_map the code works fine.

Comment: You have a `map` of `TreeNode*`. So comparison of pointers is all that's needed, not `TreeNode`s.

Comment: Comparison of pointers works, but have no relationship between the objects the pointers are pointing to.

Comment: okay getting it so, TreeNode* doesn't need any compartor

Comment: No, but as pointed out, the `<` comparison is meaningless, so don't use the ordering of the keys in the map for anything. I *think* I would go for an `unordered_map` here.

Comment: even for unordered_map the same logic goes right? Does using unordered_map guarantee in this case to be O(1).

Comment: It will compile but the behaviour of your program is unspecified: _"If two pointers are not specified to compare greater or compare equal, the result of the comparison is unspecified. The result may be nondeterministic..."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

Comment: Does same thing goes with JAVA when I use TreeMap<TreeNode> or HashMap<TreeNode> I don't need custom comparator?

Comment: You're missing one of the points the above commentators are trying to make. If you map to the address of a TreeNode, you're organizing the map based on where the node is, not what it is holding. This is almost never what you want. Example: you drop off your car at the shop for repairs. When you go back to pick it up, the mechanic refuses to give you your car back because you are not standing in the exact same spot you were when you dropped it off and thus cannot be the proper owner. Instead they give your car to a complete stranger who is standing in the right spot.

Comment: @RichardCritten OP is not using comparison operators in their program. They are (implicitly) using `std::less`. That standard comparator is spesialised for pointer types to have strict total ordering, whether the comparison operators have such ordering so or not. The behaviour of the program is well defined in all other regards, except for the order of the elements which cannot and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @eerorika thanks I had missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a map of `TreeNode*`, not `TreeNode`.  A `TreeNode*` is just a pointer and like all other non-class member pointers, the default comparator for `std::map`, `std::less`,  will handle them in a implementation defined manner.

If you had a `map<TreeNode,int> mp;`, then it would fail to compile as there is no `operator <` defined for `TreeNode`.

Comment: Does same thing goes with JAVA when I use TreeMap<TreeNode> or HashMap<TreeNode> I don't need custom comparator?

Comment: @MdFahad that I can't answer as I don't know.

Comment: @MdFahad You can't really compare C++ to Java.  They are completely different languages with very different rules.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a default C++ comparator for user defined structure?

Not implicitly and not until C++20.

Since C++20, it is possible to define default comparison operators like this:

```
struct T {
    auto operator<=>(const T&) const = default;
};
```

> why don't we need to define a custom comparator to create the map mp;

The keys of the map are pointers. Pointers are not user defined types, and they are comparable.

Comment: Does same thing goes with JAVA when I use TreeMap<TreeNode> or HashMap<TreeNode> I don't need custom comparator?

Comment: @MdFahad My memories of Java are a decade old, and I'm not sure if I remember correctly. But I think that a class must implement some interface in order to be allowed as element of those containers.

Comment: @MdFahad I may be entirely wrong regarding Java though.